# Create a Windows Service from within Java

Tags: java, windows-services

I have a Java program and I need to create a Windows Service from within that Java program.  I want to basically run the command line

```
sc create \"" + serviceName + "\" binPath= \"" + batFile + "\" start= auto
```

However, when I run this process from within Java I get an error

```
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

This command works fine if the user is an administrator, however my users of this Java program will not be administrators.  How do I create a Windows Service from within Java (or by running external programs) without the user having administrator privileges?

Edit: Apparently this isn't possible.  Is there another way in Windows to execute a program at machine start up other than through a Windows Service?

Comment: *Apparently this isn't possible. Is there another way in Windows to execute a program at machine start up other than through a Windows Service?* yes you can add you program to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, you need some .reg file and more or less you're done. (doh forgot: regedit /S <name> will not prompt, i.e. silent)

Comment: @bestsss: How exactly do you modify the windows registry without administrator privileges?

Comment: @bestsss: Also will these processes be run regardless of the user logged in?

Comment: no, of course; you need admin/power user for that stuff, each user can modify the registry for their own part, HKEY_CURRENT_USER... is modifyable by anyone, that's the point. But there is an instance per user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create service in windows without Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to create a windows service without Administrator privileges. Similarly, you won't be able to launch any executables through the System Configuration Utility's startup tab (msconfig). If you're unable to obtain Administrator privileges, would it be enough to create a shortcut in your account's startup folder?

If this is something you need just for you then that should do the trick. If this is something you'll need for multiple user accounts you'll need to be an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Adding a service requires administrator privileges.

Comment: Well that's not what I wanted to hear.

Comment: It is this way because it is a big security risk if windows allow the Non-Administrator users to create service. However if you can tell the problem that what is your purpose of creating Service then maybe someone can suggest an alternate solution to the problem.

Comment: I have a program that needs to start at machine startup, is there another way to do this?