# Can we create windows service from Java?

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

Can we create windows service from Java? I want some (possibly non-Java) application to run as a service and I want to configure that from within my Java program.

Also: can we pass parameters to services? Also, please help me with deleting any existing service and restarting it on crash.

this question is not same as running java program from service its the other way round i want to create service using a java program, **on server side**

Comment: @Joachim Sauer -that question makes a java program a service of windows, i dint asked the same. i want to create a window service from java its bit different.

Comment: @Varun: so you want to create a Service definition that runs *some other code*, but you want to create it from within your Java code? Is this correct?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer- thats bit correct not necessary some code, it can be any application say i want to create a service that starts window media player

Comment: Then maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265883/create-a-windows-service-from-within-java) is more relevant to you.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - that question says its not possible without admin rights. what in case i have admin rights on that machine?

Comment: @Varun: read the question, it has some hints for you. I don't know the specifics myself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install your software, right? Then [advancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) does this.

Answer (score 1):

got an idea to export a registry from some already exiting hand made registry and launch it on client machine... can be given a thought :)